# TFS 2017 Task with TFVC Branch

Tags: tfs, tfvc

So I have a [TFVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QHlZ.png) setup that has no Git branches however when I go to link a work item, it only comes up with [Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz50e.png), how do I link work items to TFVC branches? The only documentation I find all uses Git, for everything.

I am trying to have my tasks set up so that when a new task is created, I would create a branch off of Development for that task. However I can't seem to do this as everything is defaulting to Git and it seems like my workspace has no knowledge of the TFVC branches!

Answer (score 0):

Link work item to Branch only support for GIT, it's not supported for TFVC. [See Link types showing in the Development section](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/connect-work-items-to-git-dev-ops#link-types-showing-in-the-development-section) for details.

For Team Foundation version control (TFVC), it lets you link work items to version control changesets or versioned source code files by using the **Changeset** and **Versioned Item** link types. When you check in pending changes or use My Work to check in changes, work items are automatically linked to your changes.

So, you can link work item with the link type **Changeset** or **Versioned Item**, or create another Git repository, you can use both TFVC and Git in the same project.

---

**UPDATE:**

That's a good idea to support TFVC, I have help you submitted the [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20531272-link-work-item-to-tfvc-branches), you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.

Comment: This is highly unfortunate, currently our system is deeply integrated with TFVC and as our team gets larger I was really hopping to be able to organize my teams tasks and stories by attaching them to feature branches.

This would have helped us with compliance, and auditing. It really sucks that MS doesn't have this feature for its own software...

Comment: @tfsquestion1 That's a good idea to support TFVC, I have help you submitted the user voice here, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.